# Should we define our interface to make it more testable?

Tags: junit, tdd

For example, snippet A

```
String readSource(String file);
```

snippet B

```
String readSource(InputStream in);
```

So if we define the interface as A, then we can only create a file just for testing. But it will become quite hard to manage the test files when some time passed.  So using the B interface, it will make test easier. I just need to create a fake `InputStream` then check whether the method returns the result we wanted. But we must handle the `IOException` before we call this method every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `readSource()` does anything more elaborate than just returning the contents of the file,  I'd definitely choose solution B.

In addition to better testability, introducing a new abstract concept (`InputStream`) allows you to clearly separate responsibilities - one object to open the right file and put its contents in memory, one object to read the source from a stream and return whatever you need to return from it (Single Responsibility Principle).

Comment: Do you mean i should create this two methods, and call the method B by  method A. And then i should only test method A?

Answer (score 1):

If your following TDD then I'd say go for the more testable approach, it's really a matter of personal preference though. A quick thought... is the code as easy to use/maintain when using snippet B? If so then there are no downsides and it's definitely the way to go.